# Position cursor at end of line in insert mode

Tags: cursor-movement, cursor-motions, original-vi, nvi

(This question pertains to `nvi` instead of `vim`.)

To facilitate editing, I created the following mappings
`map! ( (?)@^[F?xi
map! [ [?]@^[F?xi
map! { {?}@^[F?xi`

so that entering `(` will insert `(|)@`, where `|` denote the cursor position (in insert mode).

Now, what I want is that when I press `<TAB>`, the cursor will jump to the `@`, delete it, and go into insert mode. For this, I created the mapping

`map! ^V^I ^[f@xi`

But this works *only when @ is **not** the last character in the line*. 
Likewise,

`map! ^V^I ^[f@xa`

only works *when @ **is** the last character in the line*.

---

The problem is that the position of the cursor after `x` is different depending on whether the last character was removed.

What would solve this problem is if there is another command `α` (say) such that `α` acts as `i` or `a` depending the cursor is at the end of the line; as far as I know, no such `α` exists.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the cursor is on the `@` you can press `s` to "substitute" the current character. This will delete the current character and leave you in insert mode.

Basically, you could replace all your `xi` and `xa` with `s`:

```
map! [ [?]@^[F?s
map! { {?}@^[F?s

map! ^V^I ^[f@s
```

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly! (I upvoted but it will not show up until I have 15 reputation.)

Comment: `s` is pretty basic. May I suggest you take a look at `:viusage`?

Comment: Thanks! Most my vi knowledge comes from vim, and in vim I always had `s` mapped to a surround plugin. I'll take a look at `:viusage`.